# Getting out values from an array using angular.foreach in $scope

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach, angularjs-scope

I have a dynamically changing array based on another code and I'm trying to retrieve specific data from the same.

Here is a sample of one dynamically generated array under $scope.filtereditem:

```
[{
  "active": true,
  "createdAt": "2015-10-05T20:19:58.264Z",
  "desc": "With arugula, smoked almonds & chipotle vinaigrette",
  "flavors": [{
    "active": true,
    "name": "Chocolate",
    "price": 8
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Strawberry",
    "price": 8
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Hazelnut",
    "price": 8
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Mint",
    "price": 8
  }],
  "img": "https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Watermelon-Quinoa-Jimaca-Salad.jpg",
  "name": "Watermelon Quinoa Jicama Salad (<span class=\"vegan\">VE</span>, <span class=\"gfree\">GF</span>, <span class=\"dfree\">DF</span>)",
  "objectId": "x1zpkWmvmP",
  "price": 14,
  "qty": 1,
  "sides": [{
    "active": false,
    "name": "Soup"
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Salad"
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Fries"
  }],
  "sizes": [{
    "active": false,
    "name": "Small",
    "price": 5
  }, {
    "active": true,
    "name": "Medium",
    "price": 10
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Large",
    "price": 15
  }],
  "type": "Soup",
  "updatedAt": "2015-10-21T18:09:37.499Z"
}, {
  "active": true,
  "createdAt": "2015-10-05T20:35:01.363Z",
  "desc": "Buffalo mozzarella, tomato, marinated artichoke hearts, black olives, pesto & balsamic drizzle",
  "flavors": [{
    "active": false,
    "name": "Vanilla",
    "price": 8
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Almond",
    "price": 8
  }, {
    "active": true,
    "name": "Hazelnut",
    "price": 8
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Caramel",
    "price": 8
  }],
  "img": "https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Mediterranean-Salad.jpg",
  "name": "Mediterranean Salad (<span class=\"veg\">V</span>, <span class=\"gfree\">GF</span>)",
  "objectId": "nI5VSpdBUn",
  "price": 15,
  "qty": 2,
  "sides": [{
    "active": false,
    "name": "Soup"
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Salad"
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Fries"
  }],
  "sizes": [{
    "active": false,
    "name": "Small",
    "price": 0
  }, {
    "active": true,
    "name": "Medium",
    "price": 5
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "name": "Large",
    "price": 10
  }],
  "type": "Salad",
  "updatedAt": "2015-10-21T18:09:33.422Z"
}]
```

That is just a sample and the array changes dynamically based on another code. What I wish to achieve is to retrieve certain data in the form of a scope element, let's name it as $scope.filteredmenu

This is where I'm stuck at. Here is what I have so far for this:

```
  $scope.filteredmenu = function() {
    var order = " ";
    var side = " ";
    angular.forEach($scope.filtereditem, function(item) {
      var flavor = " ";
      var size = " ";
      order += item.name + "Qty: " + item.qty + " , ";
      side += "Side: " + item.type + " , ";
      angular.forEach(item.flavors, function(option) {
        if (option && option.active) {
          flavor += "Flavor: " + option.name + " , ";
        }
      });
      angular.forEach(item.sizes, function(option) {
        if (option && option.active) {
          size += "Size: " + option.name + " , ";
        }
      });
      menuorder += order + side + size + flavor;
    });
    return menuorder;
  };
```

Basically, I need  the output in this format:

For each item,
'item.name' Qty: 'item.qty', Side: 'item.type', Flavor (whichever is active): option.name (in item.flavors), Size (whichever is active): option.name (in item.sizes)

Eventually, I'm trying to send the result $scope.filteredmenu via an email API. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help with this code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not the best solution but your code seems ok except the side part. Any particular problem are you facing?

Comment: Thanks for responding! Yeah, I'm not really generating an output when I send it over Mandrill's email [API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html). I sent $scope.filteredmenu, but I'm not getting any output, not sure why. I got every other function sent over and those worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some syntax errors:

```
var output = function() {
var order = " ";
var side = " ";
//Not defined
var menuorder = '';
angular.forEach($scope.filtereditem, function(item) {
  var flavor = " ";
  var size = " ";
  order += item.name + "Qty: " + item.qty + " , ";
  //plus sign was missing
  side += "Side: " + item.type + " , ";
  angular.forEach(item.flavors, function(option) {
    if (option && option.active) {
      flavor += "Flavor: " + option.name + " , ";
    }
  });
  angular.forEach(item.sizes, function(option) {
    if (option && option.active) {
      size += "Size: " + option.name + " , ";
    }
  });
  menuorder += order + side + size + flavor;
});
return menuorder;
}

$scope.filteredmenu = output();
```

here is the working JSFiddler https://jsfiddle.net/hefc5ewe/

Comment: Thank you so much! I have it working now :), Genius!